# Javascript hiding map (iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

This is a snippet of my code:

```
    <div id='content'>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <iframe name="content-wrapper"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Bayanihan</h2><br>
    <a href="#" target="content-wrapper">Map</a>   <a onclick= "hide()" href="forum.html" target="content-wrapper">Forum</a>   <a href="insight.html" target="content-wrapper">Insight</a>
    <hr>
    <script>
      function hide() {
        $(map).hide();
      }
    </script>
```

Basically, my website is a map with a sidebar. In the sidebar, there are three links: `map, forum, insight`. So what I would like to happen is if I click Forum, the map background will disappear and will be replaced by `forum.html` and same goes for the insight. As you can see in the snippet, I am first trying it on forum. html but it doesn't work.

Comment: `$(map)` - what is map defined as?

Comment: Research jQuery selectors a bit. If you're trying to hide an element with an ID of `map`, you need to prefix it with a `#`. Additionally, since `map` is not a variable, you need to encapsulate it with quotes. It should be `$("#map").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar to this. What I did was using this js to change the content for all the different sites.
I had a main page with an empty content div and all the stuff that went inside the page in independent html files; when I wanted to change content all I did was call this function with the name of the file and it would update everything.

```
function changeContent(url){
  $.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#content').html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
      alert("Something went wrong, try again.");
    },
  });
}
```

The 'a' tag was like this:
    `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#index"onclick="changeContent('mainPage.html');">Stuff</a>`
Hope this helps!